# data transformation in R with repeated rows for a column

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, transformation

| inst | fish_ID | B | G | R | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 136 | 140 | 249 | 68 |
| 3 | 1 | 510 | 7 | 108 | 13 |

I want to tranform the data from the one above to that one below:

| fish_ID | Color | inst_0 | inst_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 136 | 510 |
| 1 | G | 140 | 7 |
| 1 | R | 249 | 108 |
| 1 | Y | 68 | 13 |

I tried to use pivot longer function but it did not work. I would appreciate your help.Thank you all!

Comment: first use privot longer then use pivot wider (names_from="fish_ID")

Comment: perhaps try `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(B, G, R, Y), names_to = "Color") %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(fish_ID, Color), names_from = inst, values_from = value, names_prefix = "inst_")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gather()` and `spread()`

DATA

```
df <- data.frame(
  inst = c(0, 3),
  fish_ID = c(1, 1),
  B = c(136, 510),
  G = c(140, 7),
  R = c(249, 108),
  Y = c(68, 13)
)
```

```
library(tidyverse)

df_new <- df %>%
  gather(key = "Color", value = "value", B:Y)

df_final <- df_new %>%
  spread(key = "inst", value = "value") %>%
  select(fish_ID, Color, inst_0 = "0", inst_3 = "3")
```